# CheckBox in ItemTemplate causes NullReferenceException for Command binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Below is a simple sample app. The checkbox in the ItemTemplate has a command binding which seems to be what is causing the problem. When I try to run it I get a NullReferenceException ( at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands.DelegateCommand`1.System.Windows.Input.ICommand.CanExecute ...). Why does this happen?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="CheckBoxCommandTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
  <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxes}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" 
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckBoxCommand, ElementName=stackPanel}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Parameter}" />
              </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CheckBoxCommand = new DelegateCommand<int>(OnCheckBoxChecked);

        CheckBoxes = new List<CheckBoxModel>()
                         {
                             new CheckBoxModel { Name = "Checkbox #1", Parameter = 1 },
                             new CheckBoxModel { Name = "Checkbox #2", Parameter = 2 },
                         };
        TriggerPropertyChanged("CheckBoxes");
    }

    public List<CheckBoxModel> CheckBoxes { get; set; }

    public ICommand CheckBoxCommand { get; set; }

    private void OnCheckBoxChecked(int i) { /* Do nothing */ }
}
```

CheckBoxModel.cs

```
public class CheckBoxModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public int Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely happening because you're using a value type for your command parameter, along with a Binding for the Parameter. When the template is first loaded, the Bindings haven't evaluated yet so the CommandParameter property (of type `object`) is initially (and only temporarily) assigned a `null` value. When it is bound (in this case just before the CommandParameter), the DelegateCommand then tries to use the null parameter as an `int`, which is normally fine when the parameter is a reference type but obviously invalid for value types like `int`.

You may be able to fix the error by just changing the parameter type to `int?` and checking HasValue in your command handlers.

Answer (score 0):

When I have done this I always use a CanExecute method to determine if the command is allowed to execute, maybe its required, couldnt say though without looking into it more but try add something like:

private bool CanExecuteOnCheckBoxChecked(int notUsed)
{
return true;
}

Change your delegate to :

CheckBoxCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnCheckBoxChecked,CanExecuteOnCheckBoxChecked);

in private void OnCheckBoxChecked
put:

if(CanExecuteOnCheckBoxChecked(i)
{
// Do whatever you want to do
}

Comment: Thanks, but no, it's not that CanExecute is required. It fails anyway.